# WCF service causes error '...'Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536 ...' in server machine

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have developed a console application which use a WCF service on a remote server. This application sends items about over 50000. When I run application on my own computer, there is no error. Transfer is successful.

But, when I copy the application to a Windows Server 2008 machine and then run it, an error happens:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:req. The InnerException message was 'Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'. Change the object graph or increase the MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota. '.  Please see InnerException for more details.

By the way, the WCF service is on a remote desktop and not controlled by me. I am sure, in the config  this part is exist

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Shorty, my console application which uses WCF works in my desktop but it's not working in my Windows Server 2008 machine.

Comment: Can you post the `<serviceModel>` section from the config on the remote machine?   Based on the error message, what you posted is not what is actually there (65536 is the default value, I believe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add similar configuration on client side as well. Here is sample configuration. Please make appropriate changes as per your service details.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://XXXX/MyService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" contract="MyServiceReference.IMyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehaviour"/>
</client>
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehaviour">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```